# ScrollTop not working after toggle

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Cannot understand, why it doesn't scroll to element.

```
<div class="h3 showhide">...</div>
<div id="comments" class="inv" style="display:none;">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.main-content').on('click', '.showhide', function () {
            $(".inv").toggle("slow");
            $('html, body').stop(true, true).animate({
                scrollTop: $('#comments').offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to display `#comments` to get `.offset().top` using `.show()` then hide it using `.hide()`.

See this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var comments_top = $('#comments').show().offset().top;


    $('.main-content').on('click', '.showhide', function() {
      if ($('#comments').is(":hidden")) {
      comments_top = $('#comments').show().offset().top;
      $('#comments').hide();
    }
      $(".inv").toggle("slow");
      $('html, body').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollTop: comments_top
      }, 500);
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: See updated, if statement should be inside click function

Answer (score 1):

Display:none means the element has no location in the page. Therefore scroll doesn't scroll.

Reference: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211236